# Mixed C++/CLI code with unmanaged SQLite

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, sqlite, c++-cli

I tried to use `Mixed Mode` of C++/CLI to manipulate with SQLite. I wrote this code:

```
    int rc; 
    char  *sql, *Sig, *DocName, *OrgName,*From,*To,*Date;
    sqlite3 *db; //Database handle
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt; //used to handle stmt for step(), its is name prepared stmt
    sql = "insert into Norm1Tab values (?,?,?,?,?,?);";
    sqlite3_open("TTest", &db);  

    Sig     =(char *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(this->maskedTextBox7->Text).ToPointer();
    DocName =(char *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(this->maskedTextBox2->Text).ToPointer();
    OrgName =(char *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(this->maskedTextBox3->Text).ToPointer();
    From    =(char *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(this->maskedTextBox4->Text).ToPointer();
    To      =(char *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(this->maskedTextBox5->Text).ToPointer();
    Date    =(char *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(this->maskedTextBox6->Text).ToPointer();

    rc= sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, strlen(sql), &stmt, NULL);//compile sql to byte code

   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, Sig, strlen(Sig),SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, DocName, strlen(DocName),SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, OrgName, strlen(OrgName),SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, From, strlen(From),SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, To, strlen(To),SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 6, Date, strlen(Date),SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);//talk directly with VDBE and execute the bytecode


    //free all handles and objects
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)Sig);
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)DocName);
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)OrgName);
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)From);
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)To);
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)Date);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
```

This code tries to write to the file `TTest` into the table `Norm1Tab` which has six columns, however it fails to write any thing!! Any idea can help to fix the problem?

**Edit:**

I noticed something strange to me, actually I did compile the previous code on `Windows XP SP3` machine and it showed the problem described. But when I compile it on `Windows 7` machine it works fine without doing any modification! Also I tried to compile it on XP machine and then copy the binary file with 'sqlite3.dll' and the 'data file' to Win7 and it worked very well!

On Windows XP I had tried a lot of modifications without any benefit, but I am now with this gist:

My project has `OpenFileDialog` object which is called by a button `Button1` that differs from the button `Button2` that calles the code shown above. The strange thing is that when I click on `Button1` then click on `Button2` the code of SQLite do nothing, while if I click on `Button2` before `Button1` the code works fine! This is only on Windows XP which is the targeted system.

Here is the code of `Button1` handler:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
      {

         this->maskedTextBox1->Text=openFileDialog1->FileName->ToString(); 

      }

HANDLE hFile;
HANDLE hMap;
//open the file//
hFile = ::CreateFile((LPCWSTR)Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(this->maskedTextBox1->Text).ToPointer(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                 0,OPEN_EXISTING , FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, 0);

//get the size for creating the signature and mapping it to Virtual mem//
unsigned long sifi=0;
if(hFile !=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
hMap= ::CreateFileMapping(hFile, 0, PAGE_READONLY | SEC_COMMIT, 0, 0, 0);//create Mem mapping for the file in virtual memory
sifi= ::GetFileSize(hFile,NULL);
}

//load the binary form of the file to memory//
 LPVOID base;
 BYTE b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10;
 int inc=2;
if( hMap!=NULL){
base = ::MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);//load the mapped file into the RAM
b1= *((BYTE *)base + sifi/inc++);
b2= *((BYTE *)base + sifi/inc++);
b3= *((BYTE *)base + sifi/inc++);
b4= *((BYTE *)base + sifi/inc++);
b5= *((BYTE *)base + sifi/inc++);
b6= *((BYTE *)base + sifi/inc++);
b7= *((BYTE *)base + sifi/inc++);
b8= *((BYTE *)base + sifi/inc++);
b9= *((BYTE *)base + sifi/inc++);
b10= *((BYTE *)base + sifi/inc++);
}
inc=2;





//show the sig
 String^ HexSig;
HexSig = String::Format("{0:X2}", b1)+String::Format("{0:X2}", b2)+String::Format("{0:X2}", b3)+String::Format("{0:X2}", b4)+String::Format("{0:X2}", b5)+String::Format("{0:X2}", b6)+String::Format("{0:X2}", b7)+String::Format("{0:X2}", b8)+String::Format("{0:X2}", b9)+String::Format("{0:X2}", b10);
this->maskedTextBox7->Text=HexSig;



//free handles
  ::CloseHandle(hFile); 
  ::CloseHandle(hMap);
  ::UnmapViewOfFile(base);
         }
```

Any one here can see the problem!

Comment: Why are you using `Marshal::FreeHGlobal` in C++/CLI, when you could just call `GlobalFree` directly?

Comment: @Ben : `Marshal::FreeHGlobal` exposes the `LocalFree` function, not `GlobalFree`, but your point still stands.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Because I used `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi`! I am not sure if I understood you!

Comment: @ildjarn: Then it's the worst-named function ever.

Comment: @Ben : I won't argue there...

Comment: @Adban : He's just saying that you can call `LocalFree` instead of `Marshal::FreeHGlobal` to save some typing.

Comment: @ildjarn: With the possible exception of `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi`, which also doesn't have any relation to `HGLOBAL`.  Isn't there a `marshal_as<std::string>` that would solve all these string-conversion problems at once?

Comment: @Ben : All the `Marshal::StringTo...` functions allocate with `LocalAlloc`. But, indeed, including `marshal_cppstd.h` and using `marshal_as<std::string>` would be much saner than all of this manual resource management.

Comment: C++/CLI part looks OK, this is something with sqlite. Try to wrire the same code with hard-coded strings like Sig = "value 1" etc. Fix sqlite problems first, and then add C++/CLI specific stuff.

Comment: Is there any reason for not using [SQLite .net wrapper](http://system.data.sqlite.org)?

Comment: @sad_man No, put I already started studying native SQLite, and I already done with a lot of things dealing with mixed mode of C++/CLI. I don't want to use SQLite .net wrapper. I have to change much code if I go to .NET wrapper of SQLIte. And actually I want to deal with Mixed Mode for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Possible problems:

Did you check that the file was opened properly?  Does your table have only six columns?  Is the table created already?  Are the types of the table, the correct ones (i.e TEXT if needed)?

At the end of the code of button1 you have the line

```
this->maskedTextBox7->Text=HexSig;
```

You use maskedTextBox7->Text for the sql query.
Is this String compatible with the proper value in the table (the first column)?